# Firebase isn't reporting crashes related to OkHttp

Tags: android, firebase, okhttp, firebase-analytics

I was migrating my code from **Google analytics** to Firebase, following problem I'm facing

1. Some of the custom events show correct value while others not although code used are same in all cases. Can provide code if required.

Update : Above is solved, I was sending large data so its just omitted them.

2. Prior to using OkHttp(using Android network library and Asynctask)  firebase shows correct line number in crash reports but not after using OkHttp, I can confirm that I have uploaded correct mapping file as other non OKHttp related crashes are reported correctly.

**So my concern is not exception but from where it is thrown?**

Firebase crash report before `OKhttp`

```
Exception java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect (PlainSocketImpl.java)
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect (AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:334)
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress (AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:196)
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect (AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect (SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
java.net.Socket.connect (Socket.java:586)
com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket (Platform.java:113)
com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket (Connection.java:1432)
com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect (Connection.java:1390)
com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner (Connection.java:1667)
com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner (OkHttpClient.java:133)
com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect (HttpEngine.java:466)
com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest (HttpEngine.java:371)
com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute (HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)
com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse (HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:438)
com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode (HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:567)
com.package.MyClass$4.doInBackground (MyClass.java:168)
com.package.MyClass$4.doInBackground (MyClass.java:161)
android.os.AsyncTask$2.call (AsyncTask.java:304)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:237)
android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run (AsyncTask.java:243)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:762)
```

Firebase crash report after OkHttp

```
Exception java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect (PlainSocketImpl.java)
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect (AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:334)
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress (AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:196)
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect (AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect (SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
java.net.Socket.connect (Socket.java:586)
okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.connectSocket (AndroidPlatform.java:69)
okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket (RealConnection.java:238)
okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect (RealConnection.java:158)
okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection (StreamAllocation.java:256)
okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection (StreamAllocation.java:134)
okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream (StreamAllocation.java:113)
okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept (ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept (CacheInterceptor.java:93)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept (BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept (RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:125)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain (RealCall.java:200)
okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute (RealCall.java:147)
okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run (NamedRunnable.java:32)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:761)
```

As requested code for OkHttp implementation

```
Request request = new Request.Builder().url(Uri.parse(serviceUrl).buildUpon().appendPath("test").toString())
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull IOException e) {
                    FirebaseCrash.report(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull final Response response) throws IOException {
}
```

Comment: The stacktrace shows you started using OkHttp instead of Android's built-in version of OkHttp. What are you asking?

Comment: Android started using Okhttp internally starting from lollipop, as I have to support 4.0, I migrated to using Okhttp, as you can see in above logcat location of crash is mentioned as MyClass, but not in the latter version when I explicitly used OKhttp, I am asking the reason for this?

Comment: Please provide the sources for this. Before you were using an async task which is clear in the stacktrace. How is this call implemented now?

Comment: Updated the question with code although it just a simple call, my concern is not exception but from where it is thrown?

Answer (score 10):

After initializing crashlytics in your base application with following code
(Note this part is missing in Google's official documentation)

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext());
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
```

Call following function

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().sendUnsentReports();
```

In this way you, on your next application start, unsent reports will be uploaded

You can use this link for crashlytics integration
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started-new-sdk?platform=android&authuser=0

Comment: Oh for god's sake, Google!  [bangs head against table]. How can this be missing?  How did you work out this is what was needed @shwetank?

Comment: Hey, I was completely new to development in android starting afresh from college so I guess I was trying everything to make that thing work. Jetbrains IDE helped as this instance initialisation wasn't mentioned anywhere so I looked for calling all functions which could be called using FirebaseCrashlytics instance and this one worked. BDW thanks for your appreciation and I'm glad that it worked for you!

Answer (score 1):

To your OkHttpClient add :

```
client.connectTimeoutMillis(20000);  // 20000 means 20 seconds give time here in milliseconds
```

or you can also add it to your client builder as:

```
clientBuilder.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This happens because when response of server reached to you, your request timed out. Give timeout what you think is feasible for your server to respond.

or you can also may be do with that too but I am not sure about that:

```
Request request = new Request.Builder().wait(long millisecondshere).url(Uri.parse(serviceUrl).buildUpon().appendPath("test").toString())
                    .build();
```

Comment: Thanks, but the question is location of crash is not provided when OkHttp is used

Answer (score 0):

This is Timeout issue,

There are two possibilities,

1. have you checked and tested your connection.
2. better don't set any connection timeout,if you are setting chose maximum time, because it throws an error,if server didn't response within given time..

Preventing `SocketTimeoutException` is beyond our limit...One way to effectively handle it is to define a connection timeout and later handle it by using a try catch block.... hope this will help anyone in future who are facing the same issue.

You can set time out for HttpUrlConnection like,

```
HttpUrlConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setConnectTimeout(8000);
```