# I cannot view crash detail of Firebase Crashlytics for android and got stuck on "Build and run your app"

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I try to setup Firebase Crashlytics after done setup Firebase.

The crashes was sent successfully.

[image: log from Logcat]

Which I can see them in firebase dashboard.

[image: Firebase Dashboard crashes]

But When I enter crashlytics to see crash detail.

I got stuck on step 3 (Build and run your app , We'll be listening for your app to communicate with our servers.).

I already try uninstall-reinstall , remove fabric or firebase crash report part but not working at all.

[image]

Here is firebase,fabric,crashlytics version I use.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9@aar') 
{
    transitive = true;
}
```

Any solution?

Comment: I have the same problem @@

Comment: Hey @user1047504
Have you got solution for this as I'm facing the same issue. I have tried below given solutions but none of them helped and it's quite frustrating that official google docs are of no help (even firecast viedos). Please let me know if issue was solved.

Answer (score 29):

Guys I have commented earlier here for solution but fortunately got its solution on my own.

Initialization of app is not mentioned anywhere to get crashlytics report on our console!

**Step 1.** First follow [the official doc's link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started-new-sdk?platform=android&authuser=0) to include all dependencies as it is given there and setup your firebase app through firebase console.

**Step 2.** Now do the following initialization in your base application class or base activity class.

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext());
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
```

Now clean you project and do some force crash for few times, you should be able to see your crashlytics report on your firebase console

Refer this answer also [OkHttp timeout issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59961551/6743289)

Comment: FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true); fixed my issue.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Adding "FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);" fixed my issue.

Comment: This works for me (March 2023)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.I was working in an old project with the old Fabric Crashlytics and Google Analytics

So, this are the steps I did to see the screen in Firebase of "Installation successful!"

1. Delete everything related to Fabric from the project-level build.gradle
2. Delete everything related to Fabric from the app-level build.gradle
3. Search and delete all calls to Crashlytics within the project
4. Clean Project
5. Build Project
6. and finally, start again following the steps [from this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=0&platform=android)

The first 4 steps were the most important in my case. They cleaned every trace of the Fabric library that I had previously installed.

Comment: I success after clear gradle cache and refresh dependency of project, here's cmd to run in terminal. (Android Studio's clean and rebuild project not working to me.)
`./gradlew cleanBuildCache`
   and
`./gradlew --refresh-dependencies`

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Document also tells us **to wait 5 minutes** https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=android

This is what is said in document :

> To test the implementation, press the button in your app to force the
> crash, then reopen your app so that Crashlytics can send the crash
> report to Firebase. **It may take up to five minutes for the report to**
> **appear in the Firebase console.**

I also followed [@Shetank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6743289/shwetank)s answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59906454/14784590

And its working after few crashes in two different devices.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your dependencies according to the [Get Started page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started#android).

It should be something like:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9')
```

Remove the line:

> transitive = true;

Comment: By the way , I cannot change com.google.gms:google-services to 4.2.0 because it make NullPointerException in gradle sync step.

Comment: @user1047504 how do you fixed this issue as I am stuck on this phase also

Comment: @Houssam I already change to use other service but I found that contact to firebase support is most helpful for this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple apps in the project then make sure that right app is selected for communication in the Firebase crashlytics console.
I searched everything on the web, at the end I realized that I have selected the wrong app in crashlytics console.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as well and tried out all the possible solutions. I just deleted the project from firebase console and recreate the project. It works for me.

**Note:** It is not a good approach If you have a lot of data in your firebase project. I would suggest using this approach If you are using firebase only for crashlytics.

Answer (score 0):

my case i selected Crashlytic for android, not ios