# New Firebase Crashlytics SDK not communicating with android project

Tags: firebase, crashlytics

I applied all sdk, implementation, classpath and plugin of new Firebase crashlytics but not connecting or communicating to firebase crashlytics.

It always show loader while i open crashlytics page in firebase console.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63342393/8200631

Comment: Sorry i didn't say that which platform, this issue is in Android

Comment: You must also crash your app for the console to load past the onboarding screen. https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=androidhave you done this?

Comment: @ShreedharVyas Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54707667/i-cannot-view-crash-detail-of-firebase-crashlytics-for-android-and-got-stuck-on