# firebase crashlytics stucked and says - We’ll be listening for your app to communicate with our servers

Tags: swift, firebase, crashlytics

Implemented all steps from latest firebase doc :

Create App on firebase

add google plist in project

pod 'firebase/Core' , pod 'firebase/Crashlytics' installed

Add FirebaseApp.configure() in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Added run script "${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"

update Debug information format

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iieXY.png)

tested app with all options..

Uninstall App from simulator or Real Device
Run the app on Simulator or Real device then stop running.
And then Open the App that Install on Simulator or Real device.

i am facing this issue from last few days

thank you all for suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some more things you can try to force the onboarding process to continue:

- use the `pod 'Firebase/Analytics'` directly instead of `pod 'Firebase/Core'`
- make sure to [add the following to your Input Files field](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios#initialize-crashlytics) of the Run Script you added:

`${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}/Contents/Resources/DWARF/${TARGET_NAME}`

`$(SRCROOT)/$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)`

- try [forcing a crash](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=android) directly instead of just building and running your app
- if all else fails, you can enable debug logging to get more information while Crashlytics attempts to start up

Comment: Glad it worked for you! Could you accept this answer if it helped, so that others who run into this issue are more likely to find the answer as well?